# python speech_recognition module occupies microphone

Tags: python, speech-recognition, detection, voice

I'm on Linux, and I'm using the `speech_recognition` module in Python. Everything works fine, but the problem is that when I start the program, only the program can recognize my microphone.

Example: I'm on discord with friends and I want to use my program. The second I launch it, I can't hear or speak with anyone even after I close my program. The only way is to reboot my computer.

If you having any ideas to solve my problem thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into [Pulseaudio](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/) if I were you.

It comes with  Ubuntu - but you may have to install it on other systems.

[Jack](http://jackaudio.org/) is also useful for this sort of thing

Comment: I already eared about Jack but I don't know how it can help for that issue :/